# Tarantool queue via .Net

Tags: .net, queue, tarantool

I use `Tarantool` as a database and `Web API` in my `.Net` project. But besides that, I would like to use the built-in `Tarantool queues`, but I could not find adapters to work with `Tarantool queues` under `.Net` (like [this](https://github.com/igorcoding/asynctnt-queue), [this](https://github.com/tarantool/queue-python) or [this one](https://github.com/tarantool-php/queue)). Is it possible to solve the problem of working with queues using `.Net`?

Comment: I doubt that current C# drivers support queues. You may use `await box.Call("some_function")` to call lua functions on the tarantool side. It is not very elegant solution but it could be a workaround for your problem. Please have a look at this post [1], especially at sections "Creating an initialization script" and "Calling Lua functions".  

[1]: https://hackernoon.com/using-tarantool-in-a-net-project-on-windows-2676253ce521

Comment: @VladimirLebedev, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For easy access from different platforms, I implemented a simple Web API to access ddsfdfd queues as a consumer. For me it turned out to be the most convenient way. Like on fragment below.

```lua
local queue = require('queue')

local function take_task(req)
    local json = require('json')
    local task = queue.tube.queue_name:take(15)
    local resp = nil
    if task ~= nil then
        resp = req:render({ json = {task} })
        resp.status = 200
    else
        resp = req:render({ json = {task_id} })
        resp.status = 404
    end
    return resp
end

local server = require('http.server').new(nil, 9090, {app_dir='/etc/tarantool/instances.enabled/'})
server:route({ path = '/take_task' }, take_task)
server:start()
```